# Подскажите лучший способ передать значение переменной во множество классов php

Tags: php, ооп

Как передать значение переменной во множество классов php ?

Comment: Все способы имеют свои особенности. Среди них нет лучшего. Выбирать нужно тот, который больше подходит для решения задачи.

Comment: Что за переменная и зачем она нужна множеству классов?

Comment: почему бы не передать эту переменную в родителе, а в дочерних классах будет доступ к ней

Comment: Хорошая идея, прислушался.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Переменные для класса надо передавать через конструктор.

Comment: А как же сеттеры? =/

Comment: Сеттеры - для своих собственных переменных. А для общих - конструктор.

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял , для передачи значения переменной множеству классов мне надо изменить конструкторы множества классов ?